# Selenium Web Driver Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a weird error while trying to click on a Capybara Element

- I'm using find(:xpath,"//a[contains(text(),'Connect')]").click
- (find(:xpath,"//a[contains(text(),'Connect')]").present? return true)

the error I get is:

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError Exception: Element cannot be scrolled into view:javascript:void(0);

i did some research and the only solution i found is that setting the selenium version to 2.16 may fix this issue (i'm using 2.25).

anybody got an idea?

Comment: I ran in to similar issues once and if I remember correctly, using JS in conjunction with `execute_script` to explicitly execute the click worked.

Comment: Are you sure the page is visible when you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when the page being tested is not fit into the current window size. If you know such pages where usually these error happening, you may explicitly scroll down before doing the operation on such hidden elements(like click, clear etc). Here the code to explicitly scroll down the page.

In java,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250,350)");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the times I used selenium webdriver to test .NET apps, I would get that error when the issue was exactly what it sounds like:  It's looking for an object on the page that it cant scroll to for some reason.  In my case it was because some dialogue boxes would appear without scrollbars and the driver had no way to "scroll the object into view"

Can you watch the execution of your test and see if that's the case?  I had some luck rolling back to a previous version of firefox because 15+ was (as of about 2 months ago when I had the issue) unsupported by web driver and had this problem periodically.  Rolling back selenium versions may help too.

First step though is definitely to watch the execution of the test and see whats happening though.  And a good debugging idea may be to try to work through your steps manually yourself to make sure the test works by hand.

Its also worth noting that for the webdriver to be able to execute click the object actually has to be visible.  IsPresent doesnt require that, it just searches the page files.  Also an issue I ran into.  IsPresent will still return true for objects that are not and cannot be made visible on the page (i.e. something at the bottom of the page that you cant see at the time)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of tips here:

1. Webdriver should ideally be on the most recent update, it's what most use (Unless you're doing Ruby Automation)
2. Use css selectors, xpath (Whilst rendered), is almost always heavier on both resources and code.
3. Try defensive coding, first of all ascertain it exists. There are many ways to do that dependent on what package you are using. In ruby you would do `page.has_css?('css_string')`